How to keep the python console open in QGIS?
How to make sure the "python console" and the "editor" are open upon launching QGIS? I tried searching in the Python Console Tab in the "Settings > Options" but could not find anything.


Thanks Ben W, yes, that solution might work, but I wanted to know if I missed out the option within the interface itself without adding any programming. I will add more details about why I need it that way to clarify with the rest.

On second thought Ben W, you are right, I will just follow the instructions on that question. I have closed this one. Thanks again, not sure why I missed out that one.
